# Multiplying a rails instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and I am trying to multiple a rails instance variable in a controller like

```
@amount * 100
```

But it what its doing is just multiplying the literal amount 100 times. For example if @amount = 10 it would just write out 10 100 times instead of making the instance variable equal to 1000. I was wounder if this is even possible to do with an instance variable. If so how do I go about it Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is what happens when you multiply a string.

```
> "a" * 10
=> "aaaaaaaaaa"
```

This means that you need to coerce `@amount` into a number first.

```
@amount.to_i * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to multiply a string n times and then store it onto a variable it would simply be:

if it is already a string:

```
   @string = @string * 100
```

if it is another date type:

```
   @not_a_string = @not_a_string.to_s * 100
```

Hope this is what you're looking for. Cheers.